# Touchpad not working on an Acer One 725

Tags: touchpad

I installed ubuntu on a usb drive on a acer one 725, and cannot seem to be able to make the touchpad work....here is what i have

```
xinpbig-marc@Big-Marc:~$ xinput  --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

any can help me out....

Answer (score 3):

I installed Unity 12.04 on an Acer 725, everything worked but the touchpad.

This got it working.

open terminal:

```
cd /etc/modprobe.d
gksudo gedit options.conf
```

type into file:

```
options psmouse proto=imps
```

in terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

close terminal, log out, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> should now toggle touchpad

Comment: Fn+F7 was all that I missed.

Answer (score 0):

got from this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2020719&page=4

this solution works on Mint 14 (Ubuntu 12.10, linux version 3.5.0-21.32), and also with this solution scroll can be enabled.. just create a file:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer.conf
```

containing this line:

```
blacklist acer-wmi
```

in terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

this solution works on 3.5.0-17.28, without needing to do steps above, just create a file:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

containing:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
    MatchProduct "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "synaptics"
    Option "TapButton1" "1"
    Option "TapButton2" "3"
    Option "TapButton3" "2"
    Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "1"
    Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "1"
    Option "CoastingSpeed" "10"
    Option "EdgeMotionMinZ" "30"
    Option "EdgeMotionMaxZ" "40"
    Option "EdgeMotionMinSpeed" "100"
    Option "EdgeMotionMaxSpeed" "400"
    Option "FingerLow" "9"
    Option "FingerHigh" "12"
    Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"
    Option "ClickPad" "True"
    Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

then, reboot..