# Multitouch doesn't work on touchpad on acer spire v3 771G

Tags: 13.04, kernel, touchpad, acer

I was trying to install psmouse all day. I've found lots of tutorials but none work. For example https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/681904/comments/64 in this I have the following message

`Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
Building module:
cleaning build area....
make KERNELRELEASE=3.8.0-23-generic -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-23-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-v6/build/src psmouse.ko....(bad exit status: 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/dkms_packages.py", line 22, in <module>
    import apport
ImportError: No module named apport
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.8.0-23-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/elantech-v6/build/make.log for more information.`

Next for example here http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=95940 after autoinstall I have an error which say

`Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.`

People help me, I wasted all day to to run such a simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

1) Check the System Settings Mouse and Touch-pad and be sure two finger scrolling is selected.

If that doesn't work,

2) download and install Synaptiks Touchpad Management through the Software Centre, this worked for me.

Comment: 1) It doesn't work. I don't have any touchpad options I have only for mouse.
2) I've installed it but it says 'You don't have any touchpad device'

Comment: :( Sorry, Next try installing **`xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`** this has worked for other Acer users

Comment: unfortunately, it also doesn't work :(

Comment: Hmm! I'm stumped. Sorry, I hope someone else is able to help. All I can suggest is reporting it as a bug, may be someone there will come back with a fix. If I find anything else, I'll get back to you. :(

Comment: Try one of the following http://askubuntu.com/questions/198729/touchpad-not-working-on-an-acer-one-725 http://askubuntu.com/questions/224654/touch-pad-nolonger-working/225240#225240 they may point you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't have to report a bug because it has already been done. I've read about it lots, and many users have the same problem. But no one can help us. There are some solution but they don't work.

Comment: and does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I have kept looking and have found nothing of any help so far